# Анонимные функции в js - c ними или без них?

Tags: веб-программирование, javascript

До сегодняшнего дня я считал, что js код нужно устраивать так - 
**file.js**

```
var a = 10; // какое-то свойство

/**
 * Class - то, что я называю классом,
 * объект которого я буду создавать и 
 * работать с его методами и свойствами.
 */
var Class = function(){

};
```

Но сегодня я увидел вариант с анонимной функцией -
**file.js**

```
(function(){
    var a = 10;

    var Class = function(){

    };
})
```

И сразу я вспомнил, что такое исполнение уже видел, и у меня появился вопрос: а как более правильно? И в чем отличия, если они есть?

Comment: @vas, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Важно отметить, что в JavaScript`е ([ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/)) не существует так называемых классов, и всякая сущность представляет собой объект.

Существует 3 способа создания объектов:

1. Используя функцию в качестве инстанции:

   `function someFunction (prop) {
       this.prop = prop;
       ...
   }
   var object = new someFunction ('property');`
2. Используя литеральный способ: 
   `var object = {
           prop: "property",
   }`
3. Используя анонимные функции (лямбда)
   `var object = new function() {
           this.type = "property";
   }`

Наиболее часто используется именно первый способ.

Так же стоит учитывать, что в первом случае:

> var a = 10; // какое-то свойство
>
> var Class =
> function(){};

У Вас переменная "a", в глобальной области видимости, а во втором нет.
Отсюда возникает идеологический вопрос в необходимости|отсутствии сокрытии данных ([инкапсуляции](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))).

Comment: @erbolking, Спасибо Вам за ответ, но у меня, глядя на него, появился ещё вопрос.  

```
var Class = function(){}
// а затем где-то в коде 
var class = new Class();
```  

Код выше попадает под какой-нибудь из Ваших пунктов? Это ведь тоже создается объект?

Comment: @vas под первый, по сути, объявление функции и переменной с анонимкой практически равноценно, разница только в undefined переменной до момента присваивания.

Answer (score 5):

Делается, чтобы логически отделить модуль. Чтобы избежать конфликта переменных или их подмены. Чтобы сделать себе пространство имен. Чтобы не засорять глобальное пространство. Часто плагины в такую конструкцию заворачивают.

Кстати, такая функция должна вызываться на месте, т.е. у вас не хватает двух скобок в конце.

Получается так:

```
(function () {
    var a = 'Hello!';
    var Class = this.Class = function () {
        this.method = function () {
            alert(a);
        }
    };
})();

q = new Class;
q.method();
```

При этом 'a' не видна снаружи.

Comment: Соответственно, все, что добавлено в контекст — видно всем, а все, что вне него — видно только внутри этой функции.

Comment: А еще хорошим тоном считается (по крайней мере мной =) отделять себе свое пространство имен под плагин/модуль:

    var myNamespace = {
        method: function () { ... }
    };

И где-нибудь потом:

    myNamespace.method()

Answer (score 3):

Отличие есть. Если немного переписать ваш второй пример:

```
(function(){
    var a = 10;

    var Class = function(){

    };
}()) // скобочки добавил
```

то мы имеем самовызывающиюся функцию, которая, следуя из названия, выполнится сразу, как до нее дойдет очередь. Используются такие конструкции для инкапсуляции вашего кода (переменные `a` и `Class` не будут видны за пределами этой анонимной функции). Также различают [function expression и function declaration](http://learn.javascript.ru/function-declaration-expression). Анонимные функции играют большую роль в javascript (к примеру, callback-функции, которые будут реагировать на разные события).